# php как преобразовать шестнадцатиричное число

Tags: php

Значит есть файл crl с сертификатами
но в одном файлике сертификаты оказались отрицательными
пример

```
-38CD4AB8FFFFFFFFC49B
а должно получиться 
c732b547000000003b65
```

я проверил и выяснил, что c732b547000000003b65 = 0-38CD4AB8FFFFFFFFC49B
или 16^20 - 38CD4AB8FFFFFFFFC49B

как мне это высчитать????

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
base_convert(bcpow(16, 20), 10, 16);
```

Если вы пользовались `dechex`, то проблема в неспособности этой функции работать с очень большими числами.